# Solve $-x^2u_x+u_y=1$ with $u(e^y,y)=y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Solve this PDE with the method of characteristics:
$$-x^2u_x+u_y=1$$ 
$$u(e^y,y)=y$$

---

Set up as usual:
$$x_t=-x^2, y_t=1, u_t=1$$
$$x(0,s)=e^s, y(0,s)=s, u(0,s)=s$$
Solving this, we get: $y=t+s, u=t+s, x=1/(t+e^{-s})$

Thus $u=y$

---

Is this correct ?

Comment: I don't really understand how you've done it, but I get the solution as $u \equiv y$ too.

Comment: @mattos Okay Thanks. If you want you can post your method as an answer so I can accept it and the question does not show up in the unanswered section anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By eliminating the parameterisation in $t$, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{-x^{2}} = \frac{dy}{1} = \frac{du}{1}
\end{align}

Solving the first equality yields

$$y - \frac{1}{x} = C_{1}$$

and solving the second equality gives

\begin{align}
u &= y + f(C_{1}) \\
&= y + f \left(y - \frac{1}{x} \right)
\end{align}

Applying the initial condition yields

$$y = y + f(y - e^{-y}) \implies f \equiv 0$$

and so

$$u = y$$

Note that instead of solving the second equality, we could have solved the first and third ratios. If we do this, we find

\begin{align}
u &= \frac{1}{x} + f(C_{1}) \\
&= \frac{1}{x} + f \left( y - \frac{1}{x} \right)
\end{align}

Applying the initial condition shows that $f \equiv \text{Id}$ and hence

$$u = y$$